# Need to force tar to throw an error

Tags: unix, solaris, tar

Solaris 10.

I am trying to test a fix to a purchased application.  Previously the application did not correctly handle the error from tar when an input file was > 8 GB.  The application has been patched to use the E option for tar, so it will no longer get this error.  That piece is easy to test.

However, I also want to test that the application will correctly process an error when tar returns one.  Since I can't use the file > 8 GB, I am now looking for another way to get tar to throw an error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
% echo wibble >t.tar
% tar tvf t.tar
tar: Unrecognized archive format: Inappropriate file type or format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
% echo $?
1
%
```

...or is that too obvious, or perhaps the wrong sort of error?

Or here's an error produced when creating a tarball (edited following OP's comment):

```
% mkdir foo
% chmod 0 foo
% ls -ld foo
d---------  2 norman  wheel  68 10 Jul 18:13 foo/
% tar cf foo.tar foo
tar: foo: Couldn't visit directory: Permission denied
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
% echo $?
1
%
```

Comment: I should have specified that this is in creating a tarball.  The application was previously coded to perform tar cf foo * .  Now it is patched to perform tar cEf foo * .  So the error must be in creating a tarball with this same syntax.

Comment: Thanks.  Somebody on a Solaris list suggested a similar approach of changing permission of one of the files within the directory.  I did that, and successfully recreated the error.  Now I am waiting for my colleague to apply the patch, and will run a post-test to confirm the fix.